# Chinese charaters(or Δδ) when pasted to vim become unrecognizable

Tags: vim

For example: 三角洲 becomes \u4e09\u89d2\u6d32, Δδ becomes \u0394\u03b4, what is the problem?

Ubuntu 14.04, maybe it occurs after the latest update.

```
phy@phy-K42De:~$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:47)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
...
```

Comment: Works for me with `vim -u NONE` using vim 7.4.258 in iTerm2 and Terminal (on Mac OSX).

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with the shell.

```
phy@phy-K42De:~$ echo $LANG
en_HK.UTF-8
```

then,

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

problem solved.